# Highcharts not combatible with firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

I've built a website that gets data from mysql database and displays them with Highcharts. The problem is that in Chrome and Opera the charts work fine but in firefox i can't get the print of the values on the chart!
This is what i get with Crome and Opera....
[image: this is what i get with chrome and opera]

and this is what i get with firefox....
[image]

I suppose that the problem may be in the php script that gets the data from the database or not.. i really cant understand why is this happening.. Below i provide the creation code of one of the charts and the php script that gets the data....

The necessary libraries:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/themes/gray.js"></script>
```

Highchart Creation Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container1',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'area',
                    marginRight: 10,
                    marginBottom: 25,
                    zoomType: 'xy'  //zoom
                },
                 credits: {
                    enabled: false
                            },

                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',                       
                    //tickInterval:  4 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 , // one hour
                     //minRange: 14 * 24 * 3600000,
                    minRange: 4 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, 
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 2,
                    /*labels: {
                        align: 'center',
                        x: -3,
                        y: 20,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e', this.value);
                        }
                    }*/
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature °C',
                        lineColor: '#FF0000',
                        lineWidth: 1,


                    },
                    min: null, // Will for min and max to adjust when you zoom                      
                    max: null, //                         
                    startOnTick: false,                
                    minTickInterval: 1,                
                    showFirstLabel: false   

                    /*plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 0,
                        color: 'green'
                    }]*/
                },
                tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
                    //formatter: function() {
                          //  return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e', this.x-(1000*3600)) +'-'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x) +': <b>'+ this.y + '</b>';
                    //}

                },


                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },

            plotOptions: {                  
                        series: {
                            marker: {                               
                                radius: 1
                                    }
                                    }
                             },         

                series : [{
                type: 'area',
                name : 'Temperature °C',                
                color: '#0099FF',
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                showInLegend: false,


        }]                   
            }
            // Load data asynchronously using jQuery. On success, add the data
            // to the options and initiate the chart.
            // This data is obtained by exporting a GA custom report to TSV.
            // http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
            jQuery.get('php_scripts/data.php', null, function(tsv) {
                var lines = [];
                traffic = [];
                try {
                    // split the data return into lines and parse them
                    tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                    jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                        line = line.split(/,/);
                        date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                        traffic.push([
                            date,
                            parseInt(line[4].replace(',', ''), 10)
                        ]);
                    });
                } catch (e) {  }
                options.series[0].data = traffic;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
```

Part of the html table that displays the chart:

```
<td><div id="container1" style="width: 725px; height: 300px;"></div></td>
```

The php script tha gets the data:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("db4free.net","username","password");

if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("weatherlog", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weatherlog");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo $row['TIME'] . " , " . $row['TEMP']. " , " . $row['HUMIDITY'] . " , " . $row['PRESSURE'] . "        , " . $row['OUTTEMP'] . " , " . $row['OUTHUMIDITY'] . " , " . $row['RAIN'] . " , " .    $row['WINDSPEED'] . "\n";

}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

So?? What should i do?? its very important to run in firefox too..

This is what i get from firefox's console... I have 7 charts that call the data.php and get back 300kb [image]

Comment: Do you have any error in javascript console?

Comment: For the record, our employees only have FireFox access. The portal I developed uses many of highchart's charts and they all operate fine.

Comment: When's the last time you updated Firefox?  You're probably not on 33.0.2, are you? (Click Help->About Firefox->Update)

Comment: My firefox version is 33.0 (14 october 2014) )the last one...The only thing i get from  firefox console is this warning:  Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2

Comment: Can you please check in the console if the ajax call actually retrieves data? (It should, but... you konw)...

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: i pasted the console log in the main thread..I noticed that if i use an older libray i get 1-2 bullets..

Comment: What's the data.php output? Did you try this in jsfiddle with the same code?

Comment: this the output of my last two entries..... 2014-11-02 22:34:51 , 22.6 , 39 , 1023.7 , 11.8 , 53 , 0 , 0.0 2014-11-02 22:44:53 , 22.5 , 39 , 1023.7 , 11.8 , 53 , 0 , 0.0

Comment: Better is return json in php (by json_encode) then in javascript use the $.getJSON() function and push it in highcharts by refernece.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that Firefox can't parse your data format:

```
Date.parse('2014-11-02 22:34:51 UTC'); //returns NaN!
```

Meanwhile Chrome works fine:

```
Date.parse('2014-11-02 22:34:51 UTC'); //returns 1414967691000
```

Instead of using `Date.parse()`, use `Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)`

Comment: That seems to be a really good explanation!! But how should i do that? Should i change the data.php output and formating the date to be suitable for the method Date.UTC or something else? When i change the line date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');  to  date = Date.UTC(line[0] +' UTC'); nothing happens!! I'm sorry but i 'm new in php and javascript and these are me first attempts!

Comment: Firefox also can't `Date.parse("2014-11-11 23:00:00")` (which Chrome is able to), so I ended up checking string length and then constructing a `Date` object out of `parseInt`-ed `substring`s of the given string.

Comment: Don't forget to subtract `1` for months, since months are starting from 0 in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution....

I changed my php script formatting the date to be suitable for Date.UTC

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("db4free.net","USERNAME","PASS");

if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("weatherlog", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT TIME,TEMP,HUMIDITY,PRESSURE,OUTTEMP,OUTHUMIDITY,RAIN,WINDSPEED FROM    weatherlog where YEAR(TIME) = YEAR(CURDATE())");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$datetime = date('Y, n, j, H, i, s', strtotime($row['TIME']));


echo $datetime . " , " . $row['TEMP']. " , " . $row['HUMIDITY'] . " , " . $row['PRESSURE'] . " , " . $row['OUTTEMP'] . " , " . $row['OUTHUMIDITY'] . " , " . $row['RAIN'] . " , " . $row['WINDSPEED'] . "\n";

}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

In the javascipt i changed

```
 date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');  with
 date = Date.UTC(line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],line[5]);
```

Finally works in every browser!! Pawel Fus you are the hero of the day!! Thank you!!